# How accurate were Jules Verne's predictions?

Tags: jules-verne

On multiple occasions, I have heard Jules Verne praised for his ability to make accurate predictions of what now is the present, and past. Where can I find a tabulation of all of his predictions, and a measure of their accuracy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'Accuracy' is probably given to interpretation - both Verne and Wells wrote a lot of speculative fiction, some of which speculation has become a reality. Also, some of their science was pretty fair - for example, Wells' defeat of the Martians coming about because of their lack of immunity to Earthly diseases.

However, in both cases, there are glaring problems in their 'science' - for instance, Verne launched men to the Moon (which I think had an atmosphere - can't remember that bit) by firing them from a cannon. It makes for nice reading, but the forces from this kind of propulsion would turn the unfortunate astronauts into red paste.

As for a list or tabulation - I don't know if this is definitive, but there's a pretty extensive FAQ at http://jv.gilead.org.il/FAQ/index.en.html#C1

Comment: Many accurate predictions from the Voyage to the Moon (like the weight, size, speed of the "spaceship", the place from where it was launched, the trajectory, the travel times, etc.) come from the fact that all the theoretical calculations could be made well before Verne's time, they just lacked the resources and technologies to realize it in practice.

Comment: You are wrong. Gerald Bull would probably have put people into orbit eventually, had he not been assassinated. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Bull The diameter of cannon necessary would have only been about 6ft, and the G forces would have been survivable.

Comment: not convinced that the g-forces would have been survivable... it's one thing to loft an explosive shell or robustly manufactured sensor pod, but nothing can stop your ribcage collapsing under enough G

Comment: actually - it seems that there are other limitations to explosive-cannon launches: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/35169/1719

Comment: IIRC Verne's story actually acknowledges the problem with high g forces and the "bullet" contains a mechanism to reduce them by spreading the acceleration over a larger timeframe for the voyagers. Whether that would be enough in reality is a different matter, of course.